# Adding arrows to scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, arrows

I'm trying to add arrows to the `x` and `y` axes of the scrollbar, here's my scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk3NH/ 
And I want this arrow(image) for the two axes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Un2.png
I'm looking for the code that add the arrows like that [image] and not up and down.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've been playing around with it for you.
First I set the buttons to be 10px x 10px to make it easier, and created 4 10 by 10 arrows pointing left, right, up and down.
Then I set the background-size to be 100%, to scale it correctly.
Then i set the correct image to each button using, the `:increment`, `:decrement`, `:horizontal` and `:vertical` selectors.
The images are on my public dropbox right now, but you can add your own.

Here's the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/Nk3NH/2/

the code I wrote was this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55165267/icon2.png);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55165267/icon4.png);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55165267/icon3.png);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55165267/icon.png);
}
```

EDIT:
Managed to get the scroll buttons next to each other as OP wanted by adding these styles:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end {
    display: block;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk3NH/4/

Updated code with base64 images instead of broken links:

http://jsfiddle.net/burkybang/1z7vgfpt/

Comment: Sorry but this code isn't exactly what I need because I want the buttons as I said to be like that: http://i.imgur.com/aMl9c6y.gif
If you did it I will give you 20 reputation..

Comment: Yeah I know that you wrote it yourself, don't worry you will get 20 reputation for that if you make what I asked you to ;)

Comment: Sorry Misunderstood for a sec

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying for ages and can't seem to get the double buttons, I might try again tommorow. :(

Comment: Ok, I will give you even 30 reputation if you do it, now I will give you just 10 but if you didn't do it for me till tomorrow or after to days max I may get back the 10 reputation..

Comment: ok, ill try to remember to, but to be honest i dont care about the points so you dont need to give them

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30654/discussion-between-chaz2041-and-user2401856)

Comment: Pleasure, I actually learned a lot about WebKit scrollbars myself while do doing it

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to do the same thing, but without having to use background-images for the arrows. My solution is to use overlapping background gradients:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:decrement {
    background:
        linear-gradient(120deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(240deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(0deg, #696969 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 31%);
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment {
    background:
        linear-gradient(300deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(60deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(180deg, #696969 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 31%);
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment {
    background:
        linear-gradient(210deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(330deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(90deg, #696969 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 31%);
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement {
    background:
        linear-gradient(30deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(150deg, #696969 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 41%),
        linear-gradient(270deg, #696969 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 31%);
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%235a6268'><polygon points='0,50 100,50 50,0'/></svg>");
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%235a6268'><polygon points='0,0 100,0 50,50'/></svg>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/5227/

Comment: This is my favorite solution, because it works with simple vector graphics generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the first solution found on Google, when you have problems showing multiple buttons on one scrollbar, I will leave this answer here.
You have to add this lines to hide the extra buttons:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:decrement {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-image:url( http://i.imgur.com/ygGobeC.png);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's incomplete code because it adds the same image to the two axes in the both directions up and down and that not exactly what I want

Comment: Not about the question but this answer helped in my own problem about css thumb image ... thankx BTW...