# Designing the scrollbar track only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to design the scrollbar track only and I want to remain the buttons in default. I want to create something like what Microsoft Outlook did.

[image]

I tried the following css code:

```
.hb-chat-scroolbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.hb-chat-scroolbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

But the design is not working if webkit-scrollbar is not declare:

```
.hb-chat-scroolbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
}
```

However, if I add the scrollbar code the arrow will be gone.

Any trick for this?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot style your scrollbar without some js(jquery) library that would do this for you, it will work only in Chrome and not in other browsers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761611/adding-arrows-to-scrollbar

Comment: I think what you need is the 'customize' keyword, not 'design': https://scotch.io/tutorials/customize-the-browsers-scrollbar-with-css

Answer (score 0):

This can style the arrows, but it styles both at same time, so you could add icon with both arrow up and down and put it in.

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
        background: #666;
        background: url(img/arrows_updown.gif); /* u get the idea */
        height: 15px;
           border-radius: 50%;
        }
```

Perhaps you need Javascript component for this.